# Android - Issues starting the correct activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, launch

Ok guys I'm super new at this, so bear with me...I'm basically reading a book on Android development, and following a tutorial in it.

This app has 7 activities (1 called QuizActivity that extends Activity, and 6 others that extend QuizActivity - 1 of which is QuizSplashActivity, the one I want to launch on startup)

However, I'm super confused as to why the default activity doesn't seem to be launching. My manifest has the correct tags for QuizSplashActivity, and QuizSplashActivity points to the correct .xml layout file I created. When I run the program, however, the console says:

[2013-03-11 17:19:47 - BeenThereDoneThat] Starting activity com.example.beentheredonethat.QuizActivity on device emulator-5554

[2013-03-11 17:19:48 - BeenThereDoneThat] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.beentheredonethat/.QuizActivity }

Here is the application section of the manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="QuizSplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizGameActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizHelpActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizMenuActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizScoresActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizSettingsActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

And here is my QuizSplashActivity, that I want to show on startup:

```
package com.example.beentheredonethat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;


public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Any ideas as to why this is doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your app?

Comment: +1 for well formed question, showing research, and posting relevant code. However, logcat would be much more useful than the console in this situation ;)

Comment: I suggest cleaning your project and rebuilding it before running it again. Let us know if you still have the same problem.

Comment: If cleaning doesn't work, replace your console output in the OP with logcat and the rest of the `manifest`. Maybe you are declaring something incorrect at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is your in manifest in declaring Activities. You are missing **dot** before Activity name:

```
android:name=".QuizSplashActivity"
```

and compilator can't find your Activity. Try to fix it and it should works. Also try to clean your project, restart Eclipse and try to start app again.

Comment: Not extending `Activity` shouldn't be a problem as long as the OP is Overriding the correct methods

Comment: Depending on how he declared his package, the dot isn't needed

Comment: Ok well I did some renaming in the manifest and I think I got that fixed. 

The reason I extended the way I did was because the tutorial I was reading said that way shared preferences could easily be accessed by all subclasses...but is that not the way you guys would recommend designing things? 

Also, one more unrelated question while I have you guys on the line - when any activity "extends activity", is it necessary to call (override) all of the onPause(), onStart(), onResume(), etc. methods every time for every activity? Thanks!

Comment: That's not necessary unless you needed to implement function on either onPause(), onStart(), onResume() then you override it

Comment: You just need to `override` `onCreate()`. The others you don't need to unless you want extra functionality, as @IssacZH mentioned. As far as subclassing, that depends on what you need. There is nothing wrong with it. I do it when it is more convenient

Comment: Ok that helps out a lot! One final question and I'll get out of your hair :) When you do override a superclasses method, do you always start with the super.onWhatever(); call prior to your override? I only ask because I think I've seen that in almost every override I've seen. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dave onCreate(), onPause(), etc are methods of lifecycle of Activity and usually need to call constructor of parent class(Acticity class)